# Dv6 1149wm's fingerprint reader?

Tags: fingerprint-reader, dv6

Is there any driver for my fingerprint reader on my HP dv 1149wm laptop?

This is my device:

`Bus 004 Device 002: ID 138a:0018 DigitalPersona, Inc`

Comment: Bug report is here: [LP Bug #827669: 138a:0018 Validity Sensors fingerprint reader not recognized](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/827669). I'm voting to close this question, because bugs are off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no driver available for this device. You can find it on the [unsupported hardware list](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/Unsupported%20devices) of the libfprint project.

If you would really want this to get supported, I encourage you to [make some logs](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/USB%20sniffing). With those hopefully someone will take up the challenge to write a driver.

If I can find some free time, I might give it a try to write such a driver, but I don't know whether my development skills will allow me.