# Fingerprint driver issue hp Pavilion dm4

Tags: drivers, fingerprint-reader, hp-pavilion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dv6 1149wm’s fingerprint reader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71051/dv6-1149wms-fingerprint-reader)

I need a fingerprint scan driver for Pavilion dm4

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e3 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0018 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 10f1:1a2e Importek
```